# Android/Java regex match Plus sign

Tags: java, android, regex

I I want to match the plus sign in a string and replace it, but when I do

`result.replaceFirst("\+", "011")`

it complains that `\+` is not valid.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Should be:

```
result.replaceFirst("\\+", "011")
```

or, alternatively:

```
result.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("+"), "011")
```

`\+` is not a valid string escape sequence.